# Calling a base contract's constructor dynamically

Tags: solidity

According to [this](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/contracts.html#arguments-for-base-constructors), there are 2 ways to call a base contract's constructor: in the contract signature or the method signature.

Why is it not possible to call the base contract constructor dynamically from the derived constructor? Many languages will allow a call like 'super()' to invoke the parent constructor from the child constructor. Is there something about the runtime environment that makes this impossible?

Comment: It is possible to dynamically change the constructor parameters using a function https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/120274/how-to-call-parent-constructor-with-parameters-generated-in-the-child-contract/.